# Convert String Contents to Integers

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to convert the individual contents of a string to integers. I need to take each character from the string and convert it to an integer to add to another. This is not using C++11. Is there a simple way to do it?

Comment: Yay. Go through the string using an iterator, compute `*it - '0'`, profit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the characters are numbers then the numeral value of each is

```
 num_value(c) = c - '0'
```

This is only possible because the characters representing numbers are in order in the [ASCII table.](http://www.asciitable.com/). All you have to do is loop across the string.

Answer (score 1):

*"I need to take each character from the string and convert it to an integer to add to another"*

In case you want to calculate the sum of digits stored in `std::string` object, you could do:

```
std::string myNum("567632");
int sum = 0;
for (size_t i = 0; i < myNum.size(); ++i)
    sum += (myNum[i] - '0');
std::cout << sum;
```

which outputs `29` (i.e. 5 + 6 + 7 + 6 + 3 + 2)

Answer (score 0):

How about `std::accumulate` ?

```
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
//...

std::string myNum("123456789");

std::cout<<accumulate( myNum.begin(), myNum.end(), 0,
              [](int sum,const char& x){return sum+=x-'0';  });
```